# Returning unknown not sat/unsat with jsmtlib

Tags: smt

Following [this tutorial](http://www.grammatech.com/resources/smt/jSMTLIBTutorial.pdf), I tried this first example in the tutorial.

```
(set-option :print-success false)
(set-logic QF_UF)
(declare-fun p () Bool)
(assert (and p (not p)))
(check-sat)
(exit)
```

I executed this command

```
java -jar jsmtlib.jar test1.smt
```

To get `unknown` not `unsat` as in the tutorial.

What might be wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to specify what solver do I use. I chose [yices](http://yices.csl.sri.com) as the server, and with `java -jar jsmtlib.jar --solver yices --exec ./yices test1.smt`, everything works fine.

Comment: It's explained in detail in the [user guide](http://www.grammatech.com/resources/smt/jSMTLIBUserGuide.pdf) of jSMTLIB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `jsmtlib.jar` is some kind of wrapper for SMT solvers. The "unknown" answer has nothing to do with Z3. You should contact `jsmtlib.jar` authors about this problem.

Have you tried to use Z3 directly? 
It returns `unsat` for this script. 
You can try Z3 online at:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/chyM

We also have online tutorials:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide

You can also download and install Z3 in your machine:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/download.html